# Не отрабатывает window.location

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Есть небольшая функция поиска не странице, она отрабатывает нормально но при её завершение и исполнении

> window.location = '#'+textToFind;

не происходит переход к определенному якорю, в чем может быть причина.

```
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/name="+lastResFind+"/gi")," ");
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/"+textToFind+"/gi"),"<a name="+textToFind+" style='background:red'>"+textToFind+"</a>");
  lastResFind=textToFind;
  window.location = '#'+textToFind;
```

так же не происходит **Bootstrap** panel-collapse collapse раскрытие панели при наличии в ней искомого слова.

Answer (score 1):

Используй `window.location.href`:

```
window.location.href = '#' + textToFind
```

Comment: Происходит странное подергивания вниз -> вверх и возврат в исходное положение, может какае то функция мешает работе????

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть на CSS свойство `scroll-behavior: auto | smooth`